# Logstash Aggregate filter plugin Not working properly

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, kibana-7, aggregate-filter

Hi i am new to logstash and was trying the demo in their documentation here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate  "example-1" i was using the same exact script and input but still got different output because of this i was expecting single entry in kibana but it shows 3 entries please help

```
   grok {
     match => [ "message", "%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} - %{NOTSPACE:taskid} - %{NOTSPACE:logger} - %{WORD:label}( - %{INT:duration:int})?" ]
   }

   if [logger] == "TASK_START" {
     aggregate {
       task_id => "%{taskid}"
       code => "map['sql_duration'] = 0"
       map_action => "create"
     }
   }

   if [logger] == "SQL" {
     aggregate {
       task_id => "%{taskid}"
       code => "map['sql_duration'] += event.get('duration')"
       map_action => "update"
     }
   }

   if [logger] == "TASK_END" {
     aggregate {
       task_id => "%{taskid}"
       code => "event.set('sql_duration', map['sql_duration'])"
       map_action => "update"
       end_of_task => true
       timeout => 120
     }
   }
 }
```

INPUT

```
 INFO - 12345 - TASK_START - start
 INFO - 12345 - SQL - sqlQuery1 - 12
 INFO - 12345 - SQL - sqlQuery2 - 34
 INFO - 12345 - TASK_END - end
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
{
  "message" => "INFO - 12345 - TASK_END - end message",
  "sql_duration" => 46
}
```

MY OUTPUT

```
{
          "host" => "BEN",
       "message" => "INFO - 12345 - TASK_START - start\r",
    "@timestamp" => 2021-04-27T14:17:28.151Z,
      "loglevel" => "INFO",
        "taskid" => "12345",
        "logger" => "TASK_START",
          "path" => "C:/software/Notepad++/log72.log",
          "type" => "technical1234",
         "label" => "start",
      "@version" => "1"
}
{
          "host" => "BEN",
       "message" => "INFO - 12345 - SQL - sqlQuery1 - 12\r",
    "@timestamp" => 2021-04-27T14:17:28.174Z,
          "type" => "technical1234",
         "label" => "sqlQuery1",
        "taskid" => "12345",
      "loglevel" => "INFO",
        "logger" => "SQL",
      "duration" => 12,
          "path" => "C:/software/Notepad++/log72.log",
      "@version" => "1"
}
{
          "host" => "BEN",
       "message" => "INFO - 12345 - SQL - sqlQuery2 - 34\r",
    "@timestamp" => 2021-04-27T14:17:28.175Z,
          "type" => "technical1234",
         "label" => "sqlQuery2",
        "taskid" => "12345",
      "loglevel" => "INFO",
        "logger" => "SQL",
      "duration" => 34,
          "path" => "C:/software/Notepad++/log72.log",
      "@version" => "1"
}
```

Comment: You should be getting 4 events (one for each line), not just the TASK_END event. The documentation is wrong, the final event will include all the fields like [loglevel], [taskid], etc., not just the [message] field and the [sql_duration] that the aggregate filter adds. Are you certain that the 4th line in your file includes a newline at the end? Try adding a blank line at the end of the file.

Comment: yes after i add new line the 4 events came but i need to group them in one when i check in kibana i can see  four logs but all i need is to combine all the logs that are in  same id into one  or am i understanding in wrong way about aggregation

Comment: In example 1 the events are not combined, it just adds an additional field to the fourth event.